# Simple question about declaring an empty string in C

Tags: c, string, types, embedded

I did not get any compiler warning when I was declaring a string in the following ways:

```
static uint8_t test[3] = {'0','0','0'};   // (1)
static uint8_t test[3] = "";              // (2)
uint8_t test[3] = "";                     // (3)
```

What is the difference between (2) and (3). Is this ok to do or a bad programming practice?

Also how is the string stored in memory?

Is there any chance that we write outside the size of 3?

When I do:

```
uint8_t test[3] = ""; // 



test[0] = 0  test[1] = 0  test[2] = 0  test[3] = /0 (null character indicating the end of the string)
```

or do

```
uint8_t test[3] = "123";



test[0] = ‘1’ 
test[1] = ‘2’ 
test[2] = ‘3’ 
test[3] = /0 (null character indicating the end of the string)
```

Where is the null terminator stored ?

And what is the diffference between

```
test[3] = ""
test[3] = '\0'
```

For me this seems like I am zeroing all positions but also zeroing from position 3 as the start address and this is why I am confused.

and

```
uint8_t test[3] = ""
uint8_t test[3] = '\0'
```

Comment: Note that 1. and 2. aren't the same. in 2. you get an array of `'\0'` whereas in 1. you get an array of `'0'`. So 1. isn't a correctly null-terminated string.

Comment: Number 1 and 2 have static [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration) and  possibly internal [linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration#Linkage). Number 3 doesn't.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `uint8_t` (not `char`) for your `C` strings?

Comment: Strictly speaking, these aren't strings at all. Using `uint8_t` indicates that these are arrays of *numerical* values, which just happen to be initialized in terms of character / string literals...

Comment: @Blaze are you sure that 2. generates 3 consecutive \0?

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Yes it should. Even when initializing just a single element of an array, the remaining will be initialized to zero. Which is the same as `'\0'`.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica yes, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization): *"All array elements that are not initialized explicitly are initialized implicitly the same way as objects that have static storage duration."* and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization): *"objects with static and thread-local storage duration are initialized as follows [...] objects of integral types are initialized to unsigned zero"*

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 3):

> I did not get any compiler warning when I was declaring a string in the following ways

You shouldn't, since it is extremely likely that `uint8_t` corresponds to `unsigned char`.

(Fictional, theoretical compilers that support `uint8_t` but do not resolve it as a character type would be broken, useless implementations.)

> What is the difference between (2) and (3)

Possibly linkage and storage duration. Depends on where the variables are declared. This has nothing to do with `uint8_t` or strings as such.

> Is this ok to do or a bad programming practice?

It's ok to use `uint8_t` for strings, but a bit strange in the generic C programming case.

There are special cases like certain kinds of embedded systems, that want to ensure that characters are always unsigned type, because they generate display symbol tables or string-based protocols etc. On such systems one would always use `uint8_t` or `unsigned char`, and never `char`.

> Also how is the string stored in memory?

As 3 bytes, initialized to value zero (0x00). Not to be confused with the character symbol zero `'0'` (0x30).

*Where* it is stored again depends on which scope it is declared in. Note that the string literal itself is stored in different memory than the read/write array. Industry de facto standard is something along the lines of [this example](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/237759/6102).

> Is there any chance that we write outside the size of 3?

Yes, if you do stupid things like `test[3] = '\0';`. An array declared with size 3 can only access elements 0, 1 and 2, since array indexing is zero-indexed in C.

> test[3] = '\0' ... Where is the null terminator stored ?

Nobody knows, it is undefined behavior. It is not guaranteed to be stored anywhere and your program might crash. Or you happen to be unlucky and your system allows you to write to that memory location.

> what is the diffference between `test[3] = ""` and `test[3] = '\0'`

The former is a syntax error, the latter writes out of bounds of the array. Neither is correct.

> this is why I am confused

You are confused about array declaration versus array access. They look the same but do different things. `uint8_t test[3] = "";` can only be used during declaration/initialization. The `[3]` during declaration means an array of size 3. But `[3]` during array access means access item 3 in a zero-indexed array that only have items `[0]`, `[1]` and `[2]`.

The `""` initializer is equivalent to `{'\0'}`, null termination. And then there is a rule in C stating that if an array is partially initialized, all elements that are not explicitly initialized will be initialized implicitly to value zero. In the case of `""`, the first item is explicitly initialized to zero because it's a null terminator, and the rest of them implicitly to zero, because that's how arrays work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if `uint8_t` exists, it *must* be the same as `unsigned char`.  The `char` type can't be smaller, and if it's larger, then we can't have `uint8_t` (we can't have any addressable object smaller than `char`).

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes. My remark is mostly concerning pointer aliasing, where the `uint8_t` doesn't in theory explicitly alias with the character types anywhere in the standard. If it didn't however, the compiler would be useless crap. So it's a quality of implementation issue, even though it would be insane to not map it to a character type.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense; I wondered why it was "extremely likely" rather than guaranteed.  Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @TobySpeight I suppose there's also the highly theoretical scenario of an exotic 1's complement or signed magnitude system, where `char` has the system's oddball signed format, while `int8_t` is guaranteed by the standard to be 2's complement. Then there would be a legitimate reason to keep the types incompatible.